# Injecting local JS/CSS File to UWP WebView

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

Because until know what people have been doing are just calling the Script that already exists in the actual webpage.

```
    private void LoadHtml()
    {
        WebViewControl.Source = new Uri("https://www.twitter.com");
    }
```

First I load a page whose style I would like to modify. I can do this by injecting the CSS file that is available in the local folder of the app.

```
  private async void InvokeScript()
    {
        // Invoke the javascript function called 'addCSS' that is loaded into the WebView.
        try
        {
            string result = await WebViewControl.InvokeScriptAsync("addCSS", null);
            rootPage.NotifyUser($"Script returned \"{result}\"", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorText = null;
            switch (ex.HResult)
            {
                case unchecked((int)0x80020006):
                    errorText = "There is no function called doSomething";
                    break;
                case unchecked((int)0x80020101):
                    errorText = "A JavaScript error or exception occured while executing the function doSomething";
                    break;

                case unchecked((int)0x800a138a):
                    errorText = "doSomething is not a function";
                    break;
                default:
                    // Some other error occurred.
                    errorText = ex.Message;
                    break;
            }
            rootPage.NotifyUser(errorText, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        }
```

And then I would call the addCSS function. Of course this won't work since Twitter.com JS Code doesn't have this function.

What I am trying to find out is how to call a JS function which will put a new CSS file into the current webpage in the webview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am trying to find out is how to call a JS function which will put a new CSS file into the current webpage in the webview.

You could make a `CSS` file in your project folder, And then use [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_InvokeScriptAsync_System_String_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_System_String__) method to invoke the JavaScript **eval** function just like follow.

**MyCss.css**

```
body {
    background-color:rebeccapurple;
}
```

**Usage**

```
string functionString = "var link = document.createElement('link'); link.rel = 'stylesheet'; link.type = 'text/css';  link.href = 'ms-appx-web:///MyCss.css'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link); ";
await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

Please note `WebView` only supports content in the app package using the `ms-appx-web` scheme, and web content using the `http` or `https` URI schemes. It can't work with assets located in the apps local folder. So using `file:///`, `ms-appdata:///` or `ms-appx:///` scheme won't work here.